# How to automatically repair copy/pasted filenames from web in Windows Explorer to avoid illegal characters?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filenames

Is there any way to paste text from web automatically simply as a single line text in Windows 10 File explorer?

I'm surprised Microsoft Windows developers have never made it so that this error is avoided automatically and i have to fix such simple thing manually by copying into browser address bar (which removes those illegal characters) and pasting once again as file name..

[Rename: A file name can't contain any of the following characters:  \ / :  * ? " < >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlgXo.png)

Comment: I would rather have a notification than have it fail silently when trying to rename a file.

Comment: An application pasting things INTO the clipboard knows nothing of the application pulling things OUT OF the clipboard.  The fact that Microsoft is on both sides is irrelevant.  Perhaps I don't understand what you are asking here.